# Deleted files from F: drive not ending in Recycle Bin anymore; all other partitions work normally

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I am running Windows 11 on an Acer E5 575G laptop.  My `F:\` drive did send deleted files to recycle bin until one week ago. If I safe boot, the `F:\` recycle bin works fine but not under normal boot. All files are small, less than 25MB. All other partition recycle bins work.

I have tried all of the repair & restore CMD commands and none worked.  I have deleted the partition and recreated it. I've tried restoring OS from backup. Didn't help.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are the files you are deleting particularly large compared to the partition? I think recycling might have a size limit.

Comment: Perhaps some installed app is interfering. Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to study startups.

Comment: The files that I am deleting are small files >(25MB).  Again,  all of my other partitions DO send files to the recycle Bin.  Even when I restore an OS backup to C:\, F:\ won't recycle.

Comment: Instead of answering in comments please edit the question to add new info. This way relevant details are immediately available for anyone who wants to pitch in without digging them from comments. I already added the info about small files and OS restore, the edit will be visible once approved by a senior community member. Once it happens, you might want to clarify the "small files", unless what you want to say actually is that all files are larger than 25MB.

Comment: > means greater than.  Are you saying the files you're deleting are greater than 25 MB?  Larger than 25 MB?

Comment: Sorry.  The files are < 25MB

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution! Please add it as an answer below. Don't forget to accept your own answer after a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by my use of "Folder Protect".  I protected F:\ instead of a specific folder inside F:.  I removed the protection from F:\ and protected the new folder inside F:\ and deleted files and folders now go to the recycle bin.